# Change event on Select without triggering Click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this code:

```
var $d_docSelect = $("<select>").appendTo($registerExamBox).click(function(){
    while($d_docSelect[0].firstChild) $d_docSelect[0].removeChild($d_docSelect[0].firstChild);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            func: 87,
        }
    }).done(function($msg){
        try{
            $docs = JSON.parse($msg);
        }catch($e){
            console.log($e.message);
            return false;
        }
        $docs.forEach(function($row){
            $("<option>", {"doc" : $row[0]}).text($row[1] + ' ' + $row[2] + ' ' + $row[3]).appendTo($d_docSelect);
        })
        $("<option>").text("Dodaj").appendTo($d_docSelect);
    });
}).change(function(){
    if($d_docSelect[0].selectedIndex == $d_docSelect[0].length - 1){
        addDoc($d_docSelect);
    }
});
```

Everytime i change option i select, not only "change" event triggers, but "click" too.
I don't want to trigger "click" when changing option, and I don't know how. I didn't find answer here and on Google.

Comment: try using `return false` to stop event propogation

Comment: use `.change()` event

Comment: How are you changing the value?  By clicking?

Comment: @guradio you mean like the one 4 lines from the bottom of the code?

Comment: instead of `.click()` use `.change()`

Comment: @freedomn-m first line?

Comment: I change values by clicking on an option.
`return false` doesn't work.

Comment: can you not .click(function(){event.preventDefault();}); ?

Comment: @guradio no - OP is *already* using `.change` event (as well as click event).

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` doesn't work.
Using flags doesn't work too.

Comment: @Straighter I think you should illuminate your problem so that all other SO users can help you in finding your solution. According to your given code when you click on select it will delete all your options and 1 AJAX request made which fills your select box again. On the other hand you are calling a change event which is calling another function `addDoc` (Add this in your question, so that we can understand its functionality).

Comment: There will be more code in `change` event, but the problem is triggering `click`, after changing option. It doesn't matter if `change` calls `addDoc()` or do something else, because I'm stuck with preventing triggering `click`, and that's the only problem.
It deletes all options because when I click 2nd time, the options would be doubled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.

I think i guess what you want to do, but i'm not sure you're on the right way.

Loading options on click of the select, means that you'll load these options each time the click event happens.
Why are you not trying to load these options when your page is ready (maybe the most common way, but you could have a good reason I don't know)?
Then, you'll only got your change event and no conflict.

Nowthere if someone knows and could show an example of how to cancel click when the change event occurs (I already know that change occurs before click)

Comment: I wanted to do it the way it is because there's also option `dodaj`, which opens box to add new option, and then it would be possible to load all options without refreshing page. Box with `<select>` is 4th step in app, so refreshing page to load options again would take back to step 1st.

Comment: Ok. and couldn't you load these options when you reach the 4th step? I insist because each time I try to play with events in the way you want, it was a little bit tricky.

Comment: Oh, well I didn't think about it, and when reading about loading options at 4th step i get the idea to create refresh button, which loads options.
Thanks for idea.

Comment: No problem !! :)

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you may be used bubbling for capturing event when you adding event on perticular html if you set 3 rd parameter true on addEventListner()  then you may prevent click

Comment: Setting `true` or `false` in `addEventListener()` doesn't work.

Comment: concept of bubbling and capturing gives you forward n backword direction of event if u need  bubbling mean capture event from start window to end with your element then u need to set 3rd parameters to false
what false does it captures first come to window side then u may check even is change or click if not then u can stop it  by event.preventDefault 
or event.stopPrapogation ETC 


if u need to capturing then its by default behavior  if events

Comment: this link may u refer i think u got it from this 

https://javascript.info/article/bubbling-and-capturing/eventflow@2x.png